# Magento 1.9.1 Installation error on IP

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to install magento 1.9.1 on internal server eg:12.16.4.111 , I have copied all the files of magento to that server and when i am opening that URL, Blank page is coming  i.e. by default it should have redirect to installation steps page , instead a blank page is showing up.
When i hit this url 12.16.4.111/downloader , page comes up , but it did not go to installation steps page[image]

Please Suggest.

Comment: A blank page is most likely due to a 500 error. Check the server error logs to see if there's any information there. There may also be some data in the logs directory for Magento.

Comment: This has something to do with your web server rewrite module/config.